# R - I don't know why my code won't run?

Tags: r

Here is my code

```
for(j in 1:423){
for(i in 1:18){
kh[j,i+1] <- kh[j,i] + kh[j,i+1]
if(kh[j,i+1]>kh$median[j]){break}}print(i+1)}
```

I don't know why this code won't work, yet this code works well:

```
for(i in 1:18){
kh[1,i+1] <- kh[1,i] + kh[1,i+1]
if(kh[1,i+1]>kh$median[1]){break}}
print(i+1)
```

I want to result about every J's (from 1 to 423)
Please help me !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please include data and/or code that will provide us with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you didn't use proper syntax and thus confused R.

After `{break}}`

You must either have a `;` or start a new line before

`print(i+1)}`

Otherwise R does not understand that `print` is a function you're trying to run.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Kyunghwan Glad to help :) Please mark this as the answer (the green check mark) if this solves your problem.

Comment: StackOverflow deprecates [using comments to say "thank you"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged?lq=1); if this answer was useful you can upvote it (if you have sufficient reputation), and in any case if it answers your question satisfactorily you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.